# Reusing parts of animation from Spine in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, spine

I'm new with Spine animation software, so if anyone has any experiance, I was wondering if it was possible to reuse parts of different animations of the same character. If I want to have a character pointing a gun in a certain direction while standing, could I attach those same arms pointing in that same direction in the jumping or running animation at runtime, because it seems simpler and less time consuming than making tons of animations for every possible combination... Not looking for the exact solution, just if you could point me in the right direction... So what I am asking is, can you dynamiclly add and remove bones from Spine animations in Unity and how?

Comment: Nevermind, found the documentation I needed

Answer (score 0):

Found the proper documentation explaining it, nevermind